# Why does this assignment cause compiler error?

Tags: delphi, interface

I am trying to separate my code with interfaces. This code in my test works:

```
procedure TTestCustomFrameViewModel.TCreateReturnsIPsFrameViewModel;
var
  LCUT : TInterfacedObject;
  LCreate : TCreateFrameViewModelFunction;
  ViewModel : IPsFrameViewModel;
begin
  //Arrange
  LCUT := nil;
  LCreate := CreateFrameTest1ViewModelFunction;
  //Act
  LCUT := LCreate(nil);
  ViewModel := CUT; //Added this assignment just to make sure

  //Assert
  Assert.Implements<IPsFrameViewModel>(ViewModel);
end;
```

and this fails (Error at commented lines)

Declared in class

```
 FBaseViewModel: IPsFrameViewModel;
 FFrameTest1ViewModel : IFrameTest1ViewModel;

procedure TfrmTest1.SetViewModel(aViewModel: TInterfacedObject);
var
  LTest : TInterfacedObject;
begin
  LTest := aViewModel;  //This works
  FBaseViewModel := aViewModel;   //Error E2010 incompatible types IPSFrameViewModel and TInterfacedObject
  FFrameTest1ViewModel := aViewModel; //Error E2010 Incompatible types IFrameTest1ViewModel and TInterfacedObject
  FBaseViewModel.Attach(Self);
end;
```

Comment: In your first code snippet there is an unknown identifier CUT. Which type is it?

Answer (score 0):

The error tells you exactly what the problem is. You cannot assign a `TInterfacedObject` to an `IPsFrameViewModel`, or to any other interface that it doesn't implement (which is all of them except `IInterface` for `TInterfacedObject`).  As defined :

```
TInterfacedObject = class(TObject, IInterface)
```

So the only interface type you can assign it to is `IInterface`.

We can't see what's going on with the first snippet, but we can presume that `CUT` is not a `TInterfacedObject`, but rather another compatible object or interface type.  It also seems to be a typo (did you mean to try to assign `LCUT` instead? That would also have failed, if so.)

If you want to pass a general object to this method you will need a custom base class that implements at least the interfaces you need to assign to, ie :

```
procedure TfrmTest1.SetViewModel(aViewModel: TMyBaseViewModel);
```

Where you would define `TMyBaseViewModel` as :

```
type
  IPSFrameViewModel = interface
    // ...
  end;
  IFrameTest1ViewModel = interface
    // ...
  end;

  TMyBaseViewModel = class(TInterfacedObject, IPSFrameViewModel, IFrameTest1ViewModel)
     //implement
  end;
```

---

Alternatively you can cast the interface at runtime using the [`Supports`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Rio/en/System.SysUtils.Supports) method if that's what you'd prefer.  For example :

```
procedure TfrmTest1.SetViewModel(aViewModel: TInterfacedObject);
var
  LTest : TInterfacedObject;
begin
  LTest := aViewModel;  //This works
  if not Supports(aViewModel, IPSFrameViewModel, FBaseViewModel) then
    raise Exception.Create('Object does not support IPSFrameViewModel');
  if not Supports(aViewModel, IFrameTest1ViewModel, FFrameTest1ViewModel) then
    raise Exception.Create('Object does not support IFrameTest1ViewModel');      
  FBaseViewModel.Attach(Self);
end;
```

For this to work, do note that your interfaces need to be decorated with a GUID, ie :

```
program program1;
{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}    
uses
  SysUtils;

type
  IMyCustomInterface = interface(IInterface)
  ['{665F462B-C66B-467C-970A-52CAE9C5F69A}']
    function Bar : string;
  end;
  IMyOtherInterface = interface(IInterface)
  ['{AEAF0D0B-4C6F-480C-A373-98145908B639}']
    function Foo : string;
  end;
  TMyBaseInterfaceObject = class(TInterfacedObject, IMyCustomInterface, IMyOtherInterface)
     function Foo : string;
     function Bar : string;
  end;

function TMyBaseInterfaceObject.Foo : string;
begin
  result := 'Hello World Foo.';
end;

function TMyBaseInterfaceObject.Bar : string;
begin
  result := 'Hello World Bar.';
end;

var
  LMyCustomInterface : IMyCustomInterface;
  LMyOtherInterface : IMyOtherInterface;
  tio : TInterfacedObject;
begin
  tio := TMyBaseInterfaceObject.Create;
  if Supports(tio, IMyCustomInterface, LMyCustomInterface) then
    WriteLn(LMyCustomInterface.Bar);
  if Supports(tio, IMyOtherInterface, LMyOtherInterface) then
    WriteLn(LMyOtherInterface.Foo);
  ReadLn;
end.
```

Comment: Thank you. I wouldn't have asked the question if the test had not have passed with the typo??? The passed in param will implement both interfaces, I was hoping it wouldn't be checked until runtime. Back to the drawing board.

Comment: @GaryShelton Well... You can do the check at runtime... But you need to use the "Supports" routine. You can't do a direct assignment.

Comment: Where can I find doc's on that function? Delphi help doesn't return anything close.

Comment: Found it. Thanks again

Comment: @GaryShelton, please edit your question to fix the typo. Too many efforts has been made to get that clarified.

Comment: @LURD I'd rather just see the type definition - the typo is sort of part of the problem.  With the typo corrected the test case would fail and OP has noted that they would not have an expectation of the production code working if the test had failed.

Comment: True, the test case would not have compiled without the type definitions.

Comment: To use the Supports function the interface has to have  a unique GUID. To generate one, place cursor right before the first interface method at the interface declaration (not implementation) and press Ctrl-G.